# Loading script through ajax tapestry 5

Tags: javascript, ajax, tapestry

I have a "DirectoryViewer" component and a "MediaViewer" component
which I created. The directory viewer will show a list of file names.
It has a MediaViewer component inside it which is responsible for
displaying the last selected file. This works fine.

The DirectoryViewer uses a zone for showing the MediaViewer like this:

```
<t:zone t:id="MediaViewZone" id="MediaViewZone">
    <t:MediaViewer fileToShow="fileToShow"/>
</t:zone>
```

When a user clicks on a filename link, the fileToShow is updated and
the zone is then also updated:
It looks like this:

```
Object onActionFromFileSelection(File file) {
    this.fileToShow = file;
    return MediaViewZone.getBody(); // AJAX request, return zone's own body
}
```

This is fine too. It is important that the whole page does not refresh
between selecting different files as this would be rather irritating.

The MediaViewer then has 3 blocks which are delegated to a method to
check the type of media. At the moment, this can be a text, a pdf or
an image. If it is an image, I would like to
use a javascript library to give zoom functionality etc.

Everything is good until this point.

So when the file selected is a image, the block will be changed
depending on the media type, for an image it looks like this:

```
 <t:block id="image">
 <section id="focal">
     <h1>Use the mousewheel to zoom on a focal point</h1>
     <div class="parent">
         <div class="panzoom">
             <image src="${FileLink}"/>
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="buttons">
         <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
         <button class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
         <input type="range" class="zoom-range"></input>
         <button class="reset">Reset</button>
     </div>
     <script src="${context:layout/js/jquery.mousewheel.run.js}"></script>
 </section>
</t:block>
```

That script which is inside the block does not run. It looks (when I view the source), like the script is not there. However, if I press CTRL + F5, the whole page loads again and now the script is there, and it runs. So, it seems when the script is returned from the ajax zone that it is not executed. Perhaps this is because of how the onActioNFromFileSelection returns the body of the Media Viewer, or perhaps this is because it is stripped out, or perhaps eval() needs calling for the browser to pick it up. I'm not sure, and i'm really stuck with this.

I have tried searching for a long time, and I cannot seem to find why:
1) That script doesn't appear in the view source, yet the rest of the block does - after loading the zone by clicking a file.
2) The javascript then does show if I refresh the page, and it loads. I think this is probably because it is included in the page when it initially loads rather than being added in after.

So my overall question is, how do I get this javascript to load when the image block is shown?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Inject
private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

@Inject
@Path("context:layout/js/jquery.mousewheel.run.js")
private Asset runLib;

Object onActionFromFileSelection(File file) {

    this.fileToShow = file;

    ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(MediaViewZone);
    ajaxResponseRenderer.addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {

        @Override
        public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {

            javascriptSupport.importJavaScriptLibrary(runLib);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a bit of a horrible hack. I am sure there is a better way.

I changed my context:layout/js/jquery.mousewheel.run.js to a function which will only run when called, and named it "addImageScript". I then imported the script so it is always in the head (regardless of the block), using this:

```
@Import(library={
        "context:layout/js/jquery.min.js",
        "context:layout/js/jquery.panzoom.js",
        "context:layout/js/jquery.mousewheel.js",
        "context:layout/js/jquery.mousewheel.run.js",
})
```

Now, all I need to do is make sure to call that script when the block which should show the image is selected. If I include effectively what I had before in the AJAX response:

```
<script> addImageScript() </script>
```

then it won't work as this call never executes.
So instead, I added this to my delegate method:

```
javaScriptSupport.addScript("addImageScript()");
```

It works, but that is horrible as it means that extra js file is loaded every time the page is loaded. If anyone has a better solution, I'll accept any better answers and will upvote.